# Why is my web page showing grid areas bellow each other instead of how I set them up?

Tags: html, css, grid

My grid template areas ,for some reason, isn't working. It just shows every area below each other instead of how I set them up.

I tried to see if I have any typos but there are none. My browser does support grid function.
I don't know if the problem is what I'm setting up as grid-template rows or columns.

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Uputstvo</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styleeee.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="LogoStranice">
            <img src="add.png" alt="none">
        </div>
        <div class="NaslovStranice">
            <h1>Dodavanje studenata na listu predmeta</h1>
            <h3>Uputstvo za dodavanje studenata</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="Info">
            <marquee>Dobrodošli na stranicu na kojoj možete dodati studente na listu predmeta. Ispravno
                popunjen obrazac, kojim se student dodaje na listu, možete pronaći 
                na stranici<a href="uputstvo.html"> Uputstvo</a> </marquee>
        </div>
        <div class="Navigacija">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="uputstvo.html">Uputstvo</a></li>
                <li><a href="dodaj.html">Dodaj studenta</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="Sadrzaj">
            <p class="tekst">Da bi unos podataka, koji se odnose na studenta, bio validan, potrebno je da podaci imaju sledeću formu:<br/>
                Ime i Prezime<br/>
                    I ime i prezime moraju biti kraćei od 20 karaktera i ne smeju sadržati brojeve.<br/>
                        Ispravni formati unosa su:<br/>
                            Petar<br/>
                            Marko<br/>
                            Marinkovic  <br/>
                        Nevalidni formati unosa su:<br/>
                            01Goran<br/>
                            Goran01<br/>
                            Petrovic9<br/>      
                Broj indeksa<br/>
                    Validan format gggg/bbbb, gde gggg predstavlja godinu, dok bbbb predstavlja redni broj. Bitno je da na petoj poziciji postoji znak '/'.<br/>
                        Ispravni formati unosa su:<br/>
                            2014/000 <br/>
                            2015/0699<br/>
                            2001/0322<br/>
                        Nevalidni formati unosa su: <br/>       
                            20/0001   <br/>
                            20011/1000<br/>
                            2/899    <br/> 
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="PotpisStranice">
            <p>Skolska 2022/23 Stranica poslednji put azurirana <span class="Modifikacija">18.08.2023</span> </p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>`
```

```
`.body{
    width:1000px;
    height:700px;
    display:grid;
    grid-template-rows:200px 50px 400px 50px ;
    grid-template-columns: 200px 800px;
    grid-template-areas: 
    "LogoStranice   NaslovStranice"
    "Info      Info"
    "Navigacija  Sadrzaj"
    "PotpisStranice  PotpisStranice";
    margin: auto;

}
.LogoStranice{
    background-color: #78fd94;
    height: 200px;
    width:200px;
    grid-area: LogoStranice;
}
.NaslovStranice{
    height: 200px;
    width: 800px;
    background-color: #78fd94;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 40px;
    grid-area: NaslovStranice;
}
.Info{
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    height: 20px;
    width: 1000px;
    grid-area: Info;
}
.Navigacija{
    background-color: gray;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 550px;
    width:200px;
    grid-area: Navigacija;
}
.Sadrzaj{
    background-color:#d3e9d8 ;
    height: 550px;
    width: 800px;
    grid-area: Sadrzaj;

}
.tekst{
    padding: 30px 30px 30px 30px;
}
.PotpisStranice{
    grid-area: PotpisStranice;
    height: 40px;
    width: 1000px;
    color: white;
    background-color: #2034fc;
}
.Modifikacija{
    color:yellow;
}
img{
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your stylesheet. You used `.body {}` with a dot (.), but this is a ***class*** selector. Since `<body>` is an ***element***, the correct syntax is just its name, without the dot:

```html
body {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 700px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 200px 50px 400px 50px;
    grid-template-columns: 200px 800px;
    grid-template-areas:
        "LogoStranice NaslovStranice"
        "Info Info"
        "Navigacija Sadrzaj"
        "PotpisStranice PotpisStranice";
    margin: auto;

}
```

---

However, using `<body>` just for style purposes is not advised. The properties you set to your `<body>` element are replicated across your entire website. If you eventually decide to create a new page with a different layout, things will get messy.

Instead, creating a wrapper specific to the page layout you are currently working on is better, and it will save you some headaches.

Another (really) good practice is writing **semantic HTML**. Take your code as an instance: Let's divide it into three sections:

- `<header>`
- `<main>`
- `<footer>`

Now we can style each individually, making code more accessible, flexible, and meaningful.

I created a [codepen](https://codepen.io/mamiso/pen/dywymdd) to illustrate one better approach to your layout; I hope you don't mind :) There are comments on the code explaining the suggestions.

Some references:

[CSS Selector Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.php)

[Styling Layout Wrappers In CSS](https://ishadeed.com/article/styling-wrappers-css/) (Excellent article)

[Semantic HTML5 Elements Explained](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/semantic-html5-elements/)